# Express with JSON Data Control

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use lowDB dependency to control the JSON Data with Express and actually it works. But there is a bug and I cannot find how to solve it.

I create /create page to add information in JSON file and it contains 4 form and submit button.

And In express I code like this. each forms data will save it in variable and push with lowdb module.

```
router.post('/post', function (req, res) {
  let pjName = req.body.projectName;
  let pjURL = req.body.projectURL;
  let pjtExplanation = req.body.projectExplanation;
  let pjImgURL = req.body.projectImgURL;
  console.log(pjName);
  db.get('project').push({
    name: pjName,
    url: pjURL,
    explanation: pjtExplanation,
    imgurl: pjImgURL
  }).write();
  console.log(db.get('project'));
  console.log(db.get('project').value());
  res.redirect('/');
})
```

And it works well. But when I modify the JSON file myself (ex. reset the JSON file) and execute again. It shows the data that I reset before. I think in this app somewhere saves the all data and show save it in array again.
And When I shutdown the app in CMD and execute again, the Array is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know the lowdb persist the data into your secondary memory (hdd), and may return a promise depending on your environment when you call `write` method.As mentioned in the doc

> Persists database using adapter.write (depending on the adapter, may return a promise).

So the data may be still getting write when you read them, so the old data is queried. Try this,

```
db.get('project').push({
    name: pjName,
    url: pjURL,
    explanation: pjtExplanation,
    imgurl: pjImgURL
}).write().then(() => {
    console.log(db.get('project'));
    console.log(db.get('project').value());
});
```